# What is the best practice for setting a process niceness?

Tags: process, nice

I have an agent which runs on my customer's hosts. I want this agent to leave the smallest possible footprint on their hosts, that is, I don't want to degrade my customers' performance.

My agent runs periodically every 15 minutes and it takes it about half a second to complete its task each time. However, if it takes it a minute to complete that's still fine.

I want to set its niceness to 19 but I wonder whether I'm missing something that I should consider before making it the nicest process on the host.

Comment: It could be the first being killed in heavy load situations. Besides that, I do see any inconvenience...

Comment: If your process is IO-heavy, you might also want to `ionice` it.

Comment: If it's CPU-intensive you might even `cpulimit` it.